# Xcode Box2D CircleShape Declaration

Tags: xcode, box2d

I am somewhat new to the Box2D physics engine. I am able to put boxes, both dynamic and static into my world, but when I try to put a circle into my world, it never appears in the world. I have copied code from several tutorials and none of them seem to work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
//the world is declared in previous code, it is working properly.        
    b2BodyDef newBodyDef;
    newBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    newBodyDef.position.Set(0,20);

    //Create the circle shape.
    b2CircleShape circleShape;
    circleShape.m_p.Set(0, 0);
    circleShape.m_radius = 5.0f;

    b2FixtureDef circleFixtureDef;
    circleFixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
    circleFixtureDef.density = 1;

    m_world->CreateBody(&newBodyDef)->CreateFixture(&circleFixtureDef);
```

Comment: That code looks fine. Try checking the drawing code that actually renders circles, see if the program flow is even going there, etc.

Comment: Thanks, the code to draw it was empty. I assumed it existed because the DrawPolygon code worked fine.